# Writing data to Excel give me 'ZIP does not support timestamps before 1980'

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04, xlsxwriter

I hope to don't create any duplicate but I looked around (stack overflow and other forum) and I found some similar question but none of them solved my problem.

I have a python code that the only thing that does is query the DB, create a DataFrame in Pandas and write it to an Excel file.

The code worked without problem locally but when I introduced it in my server it start to give this error:

```
  File "Test.py", line 34, in <module>
    test()
  File "Test.py", line 31, in test
    ex.generate_file()
  File "/home/carlo/Test/Utility/ExportExcell.py", line 96, in generate_file
    writer.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 1952, in save
    return self.book.close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 306, in close
    self._store_workbook()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 677, in _store_workbook
    xlsx_file.write(os_filename, xml_filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 1135, in write
    zinfo = ZipInfo(arcname, date_time)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 305, in __init__
    raise ValueError('ZIP does not support timestamps before 1980')
ValueError: ZIP does not support timestamps before 1980
```

To ensure that is everything ok I printed my DataFrame and for me it looks good even because when I run it locally it geenrate an excell file without problem:

```
   Computer_System_Memory_Size  Count_of_HostName   Disk_Total_Size  Number_of_CPU       OS_Family
0                5736053088256                 70     6072238035456         282660         Windows
1                  96159653888                607       96630589440        2451066         vCenter
2                            0                  9                 0          36342  Virtualization
3             2469361287143424                 37  2389533519619072         149406            Unix
4                3691651514368                 90     5817485303808         363420           Linux
```

I don't see any timestamp here and this is part of my code:

```
pivot = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pivot) #pivot= information extracted from DB

pd.to_numeric(pivot['Count_of_HostName'], downcast='signed')#try to enforce to be a numeric value in case it get confused with a datetime
pd.to_numeric(pivot['Disk_Total_Size'], downcast='signed')#try to enforce to be a numeric value in case it get confused with a datetime
pd.to_numeric(pivot['Computer_System_Memory_Size'], downcast='signed')#try to enforce to be a numeric value in case it get confused with a datetime
pd.to_numeric(pivot['Number_of_CPU'], downcast='signed')#try to enforce to be a numeric value in case it get confused with a datetime

print pivot
name = 'TempReport/Report.xlsx'#set-up file name
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(name, engine='xlsxwriter')#create excel with file name
pivot.to_excel(writer, 'Pivot', index=False)#introduce my data to excel
writer.save()#write to file, it's where it fail
```

Does someone know why it doesn't work in an Ubuntu 16.04 server without give me 'ZIP does not support timestamps before 1980' error?
I checked many things, library version, ensure that there are no data

Comment: This issue is fixed in XlsxWriter 1.2.1!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XlsxWriter set the individual XML files that make up an XLSX file with a creation date of 1/1/1980 which is (I think) the ZIP epoch and the date used by Excel. This allows binary reproducibility of files created by XlsxWriter once the same input data and metadata is used.

It sets the date as follows (for the non-in-memory zipfile.py) case:

```
timestamp = time.mktime((1980, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
os.utime(os_filename, (timestamp, timestamp))
```

The error that you are seeing occurs when this fails in some way and the date is set before 1/1/1980.

I've only seen this happen once before in a situation where the user was using a container and the container had a different time to the host system.

Do you have a situation like this or where the timestamp may be set incorrectly for some reason?

Update: Try run this in the same environment as the example that fails:

```
import os
import time

filename = 'file.txt'
file = open(filename, 'w')
file.close()

timestamp = time.mktime((1980, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
os.utime(filename, (timestamp, timestamp))

print(time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(filename)))
# Should give:
# Tue Jan  1 00:00:00 1980
```

**Update**: This issue is fixed in XlsxWriter >= 1.1.9.

Comment: Hi jmcnamara, I don't have any strange situation, before I had even another program that exported to excel that stopped to work as well but I have my server in the same time zone of my local VM and network so I'm not sure why this is happening; in any case I'll try it asap and I'll let u know if it works ;) Thanks so much for your help

Comment: So I just edited my code to introduce your changes and it print to me "Mon Dec 31 23:00:00 1979" so with your code I can see the problem but I've no idea of how to fix it :S I try to do "timestamp = time.mktime((1982, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))" but when I run my code it fail anyway

Comment: If you set the last element in the tuple to -1 in the example above, i.e., `(1980, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1)`., what output do you get?

Comment: when I print it I get "Tue Jan  1 00:00:00 1980" but then is failing anyway: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 305, in __init__
    raise ValueError('ZIP does not support timestamps before 1980')
ValueError: ZIP does not support timestamps before 1980

Comment: The extra code is just for debugging. It doesn't fix the issue. You would need to make the change (0 -> -1) in the XlsxWriter workbook.py code [here](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/blob/master/xlsxwriter/workbook.py#L674).

Comment: I'll push a fix to the XlsxWriter Github. Would you be able to install it from there and test it on your system?

Comment: Also, before changing anything on your system can you install the python module `pytz` and try rerun your example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188110/discussion-between-jmcnamara-and-carlo-1585).

Comment: I solved the problem even getting the new version of XlsxWriter library

Answer (score 1):

Try using this engine:

```
pd.to_excel('file_name.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl')
```

Comment: @GiulioCaccin the function 'to_excel' can works with two different options for the argument engine. The defaul is ‘xlsxwriter’, but you can define  the option 'openpyxl'. I was having the same issue in Windows 10, Python 3.7 and Anaconda 1.9.7. However with the engine = 'openpyxl' the code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

***This issue is fixed in XlsxWriter  1.2.1!***